# Set dropdown list value in EditItemTemplate of datalist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datalist

I have a asp:datalist that allows users to go into edit mode to edit data. I have a dropdownlist within the edititemtemplate and am trying to set the selected value based on the field from the datasource but dont know how to do this. Here is a sample of my asp.net code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlOtherSubjects" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID" EnableViewState="True" 
         OnEditCommand="Edit_Command"  
         OnUpdateCommand="Update_Command"
         OnCancelCommand="Cancel_Command" 
         OnDeleteCommand="Delete_Command" 
         Width="700">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table width="700"  cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
            <tr>
            <td width="350" class="Label">Type</td>
            <td width="350"><%#Eval("Type")%></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <table width="700">
            <tr>
            <td align="left"> 
            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="images/Editbutton.png"  CommandName="Edit" 
                            Runat="server" ID="lbedit" />
            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="images/Deletebutton.png"  CommandName="Delete" 
                            Runat="server" ID="lbdelete" />
            </td>                  
            </tr>                
            </table>                 
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <table width="700" bgcolor="#BFD8D9" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
            <tr>
            <td class="Label">Type</td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEType" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="Household/Family Member" Text=" Family/Household Member"/>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Significant Other" Text="Significant Other (Non Household)"/>
            </asp:DropDownList> 
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>  
            <br />
            <table width="700">
            <tr>
            <td align="left">
            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="images/Updatebutton.png" CommandName="Update" 
                          Runat="server" ID="lbupdate" />
            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="images/Cancelbutton.png" CommandName="Cancel" 
                          Runat="server" ID="lbcancel" />              
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>   
        </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

I found an example where this was done in a gridview using the OnRowDataBound to call a sub
which then sets the value of the dropdownlist (see [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-DropDownList-with-Selected-Value-in-EditItemTemplate-of-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx)) but is there a similar OnRowDataBound object for a datalist?

How can I achieve this in a datalist? I will also need to be able to do something similar for an asp:radiobuttonlist.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried DataList OnItemDataBound?

```
 <asp:DataList ID="dlOtherSubjects" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID"    EnableViewState="True" 
     OnEditCommand="Edit_Command"  
     OnUpdateCommand="Update_Command"
     OnCancelCommand="Cancel_Command" 
     OnDeleteCommand="Delete_Command" 
     Width="700"
     OnItemDataBound="Item_Bound"
    >


  protected void Item_Bound(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
         e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
     {
        var yourLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label");
        //add your logic
      }

  }
```

Comment: Yep. I found that out after posting but stackoverflow wouldn't allow me to post my solution. This solution works as I wanted it.